# Printing A0 poster

Tags: printing

I would like to print a photo on an A0 poster, and was wondering if its resolution is OK. Its specs are below:

Dimensions: 1152x2048
Horizontal and Vertical resolution: 72 dpi
Bit depth: 24

If this is not going to work. what size do you recommend me to print it on?

What if the dimensions were 3264x1836?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Zohair